# Is there a way to disable long calls to Firestore/Listen?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

A long 1 min call to Firestore/Listen is preventing our prerender soln from working properly. The provider waits for all network calls to complete, which means the prerender takes a long time.

We don't use any of the realtime features, so there is no value in listening after requests complete afaict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no it's not possible to directly disable it using some Firestore config option for example.

What you can do is bypass it by using transactions in Firestore. Any operation run in a transaction will use its own connection which will be torn down after. See [here](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/pzhJFYPRbR8?pli=1) for details.

It might also work to shut down Firestore after some timeout in this case. I haven't tried it yet. In theory though for this particular problem I can check the userAgent and shut down fire